# Generating image preview of a doc or pdf file

Tags: javascript, jsp

Hey guys I have searched a lot but didnt get any working solution for this problem.

I am working on a site using jsp and on this we have to upload forms in doc / docx/ pdf format. I want to generate the preview of the first page of the form. So that user can checkout whats in the form before downloading it.

Hope someone will come up with some solution for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what OS platform you are on for your jsp, but my recommendation would be to have a virtual printer driver that can "print" the document at hand to an image file (or as HTML). Then you can manipulate the output of the printer driver anyway you want. Extends itself nicely to other file formats as well.

Another version of this technique would be to programatically open the document with Microsoft Word (using ole automation), then do a screen capture after the document opens. Word can load PDF files as well.  You'll have to find a creative way to get the document into a Windows desktop process from your server. But it could work.

Answer (score 0):

Well.. what you can do is..
Hyperlink the form names with relative paths of your jsp with download option. You need to write a servlet to download the form.. preview this jsp in pop up window.

or

use iframes in html create a div tag to preview and download the same form you are displaying. You need to write a servlet to download the form.

Make sure you set the appropriate contentType of your forms doc/pdf/jsp using response.contentType("image/jpg");
response.contentType("application/pdf");
response.contentType("application/doc");